$h^i(X,F) \rightarrow 0$ as $i\to \infty$.
Let $X$ be a smooth variety and $F$ a sheaf and $h^i(X,F)$ the dimension of the $i$-cohomology group.
For curves, we have the fact that $h^i(X,F)=0$ for $i>1$. Does this generalise to $d$-dimensional surfaces? I.e. $h^i(X,F)=0$ for $i>d$ (or do we at least have $h^i(X,F)\to 0$ as $i\to\infty$?)
(my knowledge is limited, but I'm aware there it is difficult to even prove $h^i$ is finite)

Grothendieck's vanishing theorem proves this, since any smooth variety is a noetherian topological space of finite dimension:

Let $X$ be a Noetherian topological space. If $\dim(X)\leq d$, then $H^p(X,\mathcal{F})=0$ for all $p>d$ and any abelian sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$.

For reference, see Theorem 3.6.5 in his celebrated Tohoku paper.

Thanks for the reference, it is way out of my depth though. Do you know if there are any cheap proofs in the case of $X$ being a (smooth, projective) surface, like the curve case?

Sure - for a projective variety $X\subset\Bbb P^n$, you can do this via Cech cohomology. One very easy way to do the $h^i=0$ for $i\gg 0$ is to take the standard affine cover $D(t_j)\cap X$; one slightly more sophisticated way to get $h^i=0$ for $i\geq \dim X$ is to take an affine cover by exactly $\dim X$ sets constructed by taking preimages of the standard affine opens under the finite map $X\to\Bbb P^{\dim X}$ given by noether normalization, for instance.

(That should say exactly $\dim X +1$ affine open sets, too late to edit, oops!)
